# Как удалить изображение из формы php

Tags: php

Как удалить одно или несколько изображений из формы
у меня написан только запрос, а как связать с удалением картинки не знаю, подскажите правильный подход.

```
$c="DELETE FROM `images` WHERE id=$id";
        $query1=$dbh->prepare($c);
        $query1->execute();`
```

---

```
<form id="form2" name="upload1" action="exit.php" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <h4 align="center">Загрузка изображения</h4>
        <center>
        <input class="btn btn-success" id="zn" type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">

        <br>
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Загрузить"><br><br>
                <p>Предварительный просмотр</p>
                    <img id="output" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; background-size: cover;" ><br></center>
            <br>
        <p align="center">Изображение товара</p>

        <? foreach($rows as $k=>$img){ ?>
            <img src="<?= $img['name'] ?>" id="output_<?=$k?>" data-id="<?=$img[id]?>" class="mg"  style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" >
        <?}?>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row[id]?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

На странице выводятся изображения, сохранённые в базе? Нужно удалять эти изображения?

Как вариант, сделайте возле каждой картинки кнопку на html, по щелчку на которую будет удаляться картинка:

```
<span class="remove-img" data-id="<?=$img[id]?>">x</span>
```

На js сделайте обработчик, который при клике по кнопке будет слать ajax-запрос на сервер для удаления картинки:

```
$('.remove-img').click(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/removeImg',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'id' : self.data('id')},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert('Изображение удалено');
                $('[data-id="'+self.data('id')+'"]').remove(); // удаляем картинку по её id из DOM
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

И остаётся написать php код, который будет принимать этот ajax запрос, брать id из $_POST, удалять картинку запросом, который вы уже привели. PHP в ответ может вернуть например `json_encode(array('success' => true));`